# Creating a server listening on a `net` stream and reply using Node.js

Tags: node.js, sockets, stream

Can someone give me a working example on how to create a server listening on the stream and reply when there is a request coming through.

Here's what I have so far:

```
var port = 4567,
    net = require('net');

var sockets = [];

function receiveData(socket, data) {
    console.log(data);

    var dataToReplyWith = ' ... ';

    // ... HERE I need to reply somehow with something to the client that sent the initial data
}

function closeSocket(socket) {
    var i = sockets.indexOf(socket);
    if (i != -1) {
        sockets.splice(i, 1);
    }
}

var server = net.createServer(function (socket) {
    console.log('Connection ... ');
    sockets.push(socket);
    socket.setEncoding('utf8');
    socket.on('data', function(data) {
        receiveData(socket, data);
    })
    socket.on('end', function() {
        closeSocket(socket);
    });
}).listen(port);
```

Will the `socket.write(dataToReplyWith);` do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can just write to the socket whenever (as long as the socket is still writable of course). However the problem you may run into is that one `data` event may not imply a complete "request." Since TCP is just a stream, you can get any amount of data which may not align along your protocol message boundaries. So you could get half a "request" on one `data` event and then the other half on another, or the opposite: multiple "requests" in a single `data` event.

If this is your own custom client/server design and you do not already have some sort of protocol in place to determine "request"/"response" boundaries, you should incorporate that now.

Comment: I'm receiving data from a third party application. if I do a `console.log` on the data I get what I expect to be getting. But the app is expecting something in return. So you're saying that if the socket is still open and is listening on the same port, the only thing I need to do is `socket.write(responseString)` and it should work just fine. Correct?

Comment: Yes. If you write a string the default encoding is utf8, just be aware of that. Otherwise you can write a Buffer for binary data.